# Is there any benefit to doing stunt jumps and barnstorms?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I only recently discovered that there are stunt jumps and barnstorm challenges in this game, for making your car fly and your planes nearly crash, respectively.  There's no achievement that tracks these, they aren't in the Saintsbook, and they aren't marked on the map to make them easy to find.

Is there anything that you get from doing all/some portion of these that makes them worth doing?  Some of the challenges/missions have crazy rewards, so I don't want to miss out on something awesome here.

If it's worth pursuing, is there any way to make this easier?  Say, a map with the locations marked?

Comment: Here is a map that shows the location of all stunt jumps and other findables, with video links showing you how to achieve them attached to each dot: http://achievementhunter.com/games/guides/saintsrow3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of the "reward", there is none. You get some cash and respect, but otherwise completionism is the only incentive.

As for a map, people are saying theres one in the game's official strategy guide, but I've neither found that image online or have the guide myself, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: Good.  I will ignore them completely then.